Not able to loop through the variables defined in terraform.tfvars
In terraform.tfvars, I have declared variable like below
sg_rules = {
  nlb_rules = {
    "ir_web_subnet" = { "cidr_ipv4" :"170.20.5.0/24", "from_port" = "9003", "ip_protocol" = "tcp", "to_port" = "9003", "description" = "Web Subnet AU-SY" }
    "ir_app_subnet" = { "cidr_ipv4" :"170.20.10.0/24", "from_port" = "9004", "ip_protocol" = "tcp", "to_port" = "9003", "description" = "App Subnet AU-SY" }
  }
  alb_rules = {
    "ir_http" = { "cidr_ipv4" :"0.0.0.0/0", "from_port" = "80", "ip_protocol" = "tcp", "to_port" = "80", "description" = "HTTP Traffic" }
    "ir_https" = { "cidr_ipv4" :"0.0.0.0/0", "from_port" = "443", "ip_protocol" = "tcp", "to_port" = "443", "description" = "HTTPS Traffic" }
  }
}

When I am trying to access this to create ingress rule for security group
resource "aws_security_group" "nlb" {
  name        = "allow-access-to-nlb"
  description = "Security group for network load balancer"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id
  tags = {
    Name = "allow-access-to-nlb"
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "alb" {
  name        = "allow-access-to-nlb"
  description = "Security group for application load balancer"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id
  tags = {
    Name = "allow-access-to-alb"
  }
}
    
resource "aws_vpc_security_group_ingress_rule" "nlb-rules" {
  for_each          = var.sg_rules
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.nlb.id
  cidr_ipv4         = each.value.nlb_rules["cidr_ipv4"]
  from_port         = each.value.nlb_rules["from_port"]
  ip_protocol       = each.value.nlb_rules["ip_protocol"]
  to_port           = each.value.nlb_rules["to_port"]
  description       = each.value.nlb_rules["description"]
}
    
resource "aws_vpc_security_group_ingress_rule" "alb-rules" {
  for_each          = var.sg_rules
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.alb.id
  cidr_ipv4         = each.value.alb_rules["cidr_ipv4"]
  from_port         = each.value.alb_rules["from_port"]
  ip_protocol       = each.value.alb_rules["ip_protocol"]
  to_port           = each.value.alb_rules["to_port"]
  description       = each.value.alb_rules["description"]
}

I am getting an error:

each.value is object with 28 attributes. This object does not have an attribute named "alb_rules".


Your variable is actually of type map(map(map(string))). For your code to work, you need to reference the correct key. It requires a small adjustment:
resource "aws_security_group" "nlb" {
  name        = "allow-access-to-nlb"
  description = "Security group for network load balancer"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id
  tags = {
    Name = "allow-access-to-nlb"
  }
}
resource "aws_security_group" "alb" {
  name        = "allow-access-to-nlb"
  description = "Security group for application load balancer"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id
  tags = {
    Name = "allow-access-to-alb"
  }
}

resource "aws_vpc_security_group_ingress_rule" "nlb-rules" {
  for_each          = var.sg_rules.nlb_rules
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.nlb.id
  cidr_ipv4         = each.value.cidr_ipv4
  from_port         = each.value.from_port
  ip_protocol       = each.value.ip_protocol
  to_port           = each.value.to_port
  description       = each.value.description
}

resource "aws_vpc_security_group_ingress_rule" "alb-rules" {
  for_each          = var.sg_rules.alb_rules
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.alb.id
  cidr_ipv4         = each.value.cidr_ipv4
  from_port         = each.value.from_port
  ip_protocol       = each.value.ip_protocol
  to_port           = each.value.to_port
  description       = each.value.description
}

